# Which is the command for show all property of my PC on terminal

Tags: terminal

Which is the command for get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`screenfetch` does that also. It also includes themes.

Comment: Sounds more like it. At least it's more functional that that `archey` script.

Answer (score 1):

```
# dmidecode
```

is a good beginning.

Answer (score 1):

[Google image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZis3eDODTvGlUaEQJ104ClHZuNL0EOzII_1hhm2bsNV7XpTp5JiBLTX4RELwBx-r1at7U8EzJRbqVQlJ4dDlhM8lGm-Ex1AWNpyZur7j01FY4Q03S6kJoZzuftpkDUB_12M0gMvRg4Ch2PTeh-Q1LP_1tvDW6KBbHSYSYGovZg2fZUFSNwn6UvnuoLQtY7CQPallrefnqsh1IR01Zs-iOYFKzzhy8fMa7K-p5ojeIrgXN-iqVKaKfwBfCmZATNsUVnD6NAAYZDaP1csyYA4U0zVNfjsQsWVikom3IuUgl6jqtwjFhX8oJcT3kcLHM_117rYRAhBK6rEOL6n-PhcKEHy9mWWjSIY7o08eSlgS7Jr6vZZbdI5wA-hLVHNfqSh7y_1ZhZIZTHoqw2JoSXWYm86v0jvSXWrxEOHRUeEStXSOOsJxhtFc9AnoBuxishgWI9ZGBs6zzRV2w2M-jezfT3zgsi7SQvHzZY_1Nv6giK3P44uZKJy1DptA-G-8-n81XKzjFguSHMkocPZbAj7yc6YeHg-2TCR7gje_1ULtqG7jO_19TJ_12apNTvsUc8SY5Z36j4ltgbuXJFxpoORQGunea2EaUqWnQjgvRTOeMY8jelB_1j_1TR03vGi7wbGbhh-BKqlrUkhDWsHjjH7HjggYkM37ITo43OL5hGvh31WSrIThVxMTE_1NaCxrn0grd8IKjz6AgRpg1RgBPbLm8x6yJMPhsyKUtUxPCOZwtmg80odkUg2UIE5YWDFSCbuuazT5wSXqiOcl_1B2-Weyzgn5Xgx2rkJpgMrkVS_1AU3bc-vDLRcBAzaI7lmrL1vglfpFneUj_14ZQdZ8mvyandUuCzMAHXHXKC6fqj05C_1emCR2k2k4tnS5yJz6v6G2sj64B53m-HeEutriQOdfG7kodJBvU0iliwcRlhZhZBZqqPHNKQF_1kIjW-x41os3NvgQzyxM8maaBJzaU8gMw8HPIzZUGx5onp8J4I8U8BcPI0HJN_1f2Ducm76VBzBtUVPQfnOeUUNt4JyaftXN_1NIpwMQiyA0zQclGHGYUHU1q9N8yBGYASCTzbB73dfx4fYV1s4KROuozxx8B3ugxTmJfAbaDO9nEewVzftXv3JysLrgXrApZ3TKTuSHfA0zM4x6-HjUIxI3p8WKzS8vBMHo5ganAtd3O1ayM8IF43I3QK-AJ1p5KKJ70pea9yA40D2r8WmgVhqsVzfj6gSxlyWij5UJwIG1gHWduO5Xuj6AtV2ivMEBRF8Dhulnaj2JPlsDtVbVWoIigD8xIn2wlss_1Ge1at9K6kHJ_1Awl-waKX0CCOep8YAuHT3qDaI_1zEd_1AaHE08zcAo5UFyPcD0fiBySBfDvN-k5xOPXflxVcMrKqz-5XHgDoUuhiCzpAwt0SNF3IxhhcQTTdqSYQP9HmGwHBQIJYnR7g0kAnFr_1lsHgFVewTSDLvmrby-90-4Yec4Oa2JBfQ9SkRkpIrqjtRLJiqf4ypw-M4gQF_1cG7yruOKolOcINXnDpG8HhGs2nVPg365mrd_1S4-HBlp1LRBq2_1pLS&btnG=Search%20by%20image) is your friend.

That points to some [archey python script](https://github.com/djmelik/archey). Not that I've managed to get anything out of it.